# startActivityForResult(), how does it work?

Tags: android, view, android-activity, get, return-value

Im working on my level-selector activity right now and I want to get the result from wich level I chose in my MainGameView, that is run by another activity. How would I go about doing this?

This is what Ive for when you choose level 1:

```
     Button test1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.test1);
     test1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
            setLevel(1);
            Intent start = new Intent("nielsen.happy.activities.HAPPYACTIVITY");
            startActivityForResult(start, getLevel());
            finish();
        }
    });
```

but where do I go from here? How do I get this value into my view so I can change bitmaps and other values depending on what level they chose? Is there something I need to do in my `"HappyActivity"`(MainGameAcitvity) to get the result? cus right now its returning `0`

explenation of how games set up: Menu -> levelselector -> Game. So I need to get result from levelselector into game, so it knows what level to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(updated corrected response)**
Don't use startActivityForResult().

Try this for Activity A:


`Intent start = new Intent("nielsen.happy.activities.HAPPYACTIVITY");
start.putExtra("level", getLevel());

startActivity(start);

finish();`

Then in Activity B, do this:


`Extras mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

int level = mBundle.getInt("level");`

(original, incorrect response)
Lets call activity A the one that houses your sample code above.
Lets call activity B the one that you refer to as HAPPACTIVITY.

Activity A calls startActivityForResult() with a request code.
Activity B starts up and before exiting, you call setResult(int code).

When activity B finishes, A returns to the top via the method onActivityResult().

Implement an onActivityResult() and see what attributes you get.

FYI there is a condition where setResult(RESULT_OK) or setResult(RESULT_CANCELED) will not trigger onActivityResult() in A (I can't recall what the case is).

Comment: But I need to set the result in activity A, so that when activity B starts and calls my gameView, it knows which level was chosen in activity A

Comment: Sounds like you want to use an intent not startActivityForResult.

Comment: Let me clarify. In your intent for starting activity B, add another field called 'level' and in your onCreate() of activity B, read the intent in.

startActvityForResult() is intended for A starting B, B doing something, and then B exiting and passing something back to A (kind of like a reverse intent).

Comment: ooooh! now I understand what u were saying, will try this.

Comment: I updated my response, just in case you still have some confusion.

Comment: When I try your new answer eclipse tells me I have to create the method "Extras". Im probably just missing something u though were obvious enough to not mention :P but never worked with activities like this so have no clue

Comment: Your way seems alot smoother then mine if I could get it to work. But cant use "Extras" in the onCreate() for activity B. eclipse wotn recognise it as anything

Comment: actually, when I changed "Extras" to "Bundle" it worked fine. will this matter?

Comment: Sounds correct. I didn't have my IDE readily available to validate if it was Extras or Bundle and I always forget which it is. :)

Comment: ok, well, it seems to work for now so I accepted your answer and thank you very much good sir :)